# How to change number of items in alpine color picker?

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I add color picker from https://codepen.io/mithicher/pen/LYpXxmX into my tailwindcss 2 / Alpinejs 2.8 app
and it works, but it shows color items 3 circles in 1 row and I did not find how can I change it in code :

```
    <di v class="rounded-md bg-white shadow-xs px-4 py-3">
        <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-2">
            <template x-for="(color, index) in colorPickerColors" :key="index">
                <div
                    class="px-2"
                >
                    <template x-if="colorSelected === color">
                        <div
                            class="w-8 h-8 inline-flex rounded-full cursor-pointer border-4 border-white"
                            :style="`background: ${color}; box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);`"
                        ></div>
                    </template>

                    <template x-if="colorSelected != color">
                        <div
                            @click="colorSelected = color"
                            @keydown.enter="colorSelected = color"
                            role="checkbox"
                            tabindex="0"
                            :aria-checked="colorSelected"
                            class="w-8 h-8 inline-flex rounded-full cursor-pointer border-4 border-white focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                            :style="`background: ${color};`"
                        ></div>
                    </template>
                </div>
            </template>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As I have 18 itemms in colorPickerColors array I need to show them 6 items in any of 3 rows.

Any hint how can I do it in code above ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [codepen link](https://codepen.io/mithicher/pen/LYpXxmX), change width to `w-56` instead of `w-40` to create more space for 6 circles.

Then instead of `flex flex-wrap`, use `grid grid-cols-6`

**Edit:**

- I highly recommend [CSS Grid videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4-IK0AVhVjPv5tfS82UF_iQgFp4Bl998) from Kevin Powell.
- Please check [Tailwind Grid Template](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-columns).

Comment: Thanks it helped. It is clear with w-56 - we set more default width for color items. But could you explain please grid grid-cols-6 ? Is it some other way of layout. I know flex rather good, but that is something new for me...

Comment: @mstdmstd Please check my updated answer.

Comment: looks like  CSS Grid - some seprate library. Can it be too complicated all tailwindcss/ flex/CSS Grid in one project?

Comment: No complication at all.